# macOS app StatusBar icon only appears when Xcode is focussed

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm building a macOS app with a StatusBar icon in Xcode (13.2, Swift 5) for personal use.

When I build in the dev environment it works as expected and the StatusBar icon appears.

[image]

To create the production app I go to Product > Archive > Distribute App > Copy App, and it creates a .app file with no errors (this method works for other apps without signing).

When I run the .app file, I see the app running in my processes, but no StatusBar icon appears.

Then if I switch to Xcode while the app is running, the StatusBar icon for the production app shows up. I know it's the distribution app because if I run the development build again I see two icons.

[image]

And if I kill the process one goes away.

Relevant code -

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:NSStatusItem.squareLength)
    let popover = NSPopover()
    var eventMonitor: EventMonitor?
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        if let button = self.statusItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("MenuBarIcons"))
            button.action = #selector(AppDelegate.togglePopover(_:))
        }
        
        self.popover.contentViewController = ViewController.newInstance()
        self.popover.animates = false
        
        self.eventMonitor = EventMonitor(mask: [.leftMouseDown, .rightMouseDown]) { [weak self] event in
            if let strongSelf = self, strongSelf.popover.isShown {
                strongSelf.closePopover(sender: event)
            }
        }
    }
```

Questions are:

1. Why does the distribution app StatusBar icon only appear when I'm focused on Xcode?
2. What can I do to get the icon to always show up?

Comment: What is `EventMonitor`?

Comment: It closes the Popover if the user clicks somewhere else on the screen. I implemented it after I had the problem though so that's not it.